# Resizable iframes jquery

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, frameset

I want to have a `<frameset>` while using HTML5 and I managed to create something using html code and I want to make the two iframes resizable but also stay side by side and I have a problem between the two iframes because my code makes them resize independently and I want to have a resize like the one that is implemented in the old `<frameset>`.

This is my html code:

```
<body>
    <div class="resizable1">
        <iframe class="menu" src="menu.html"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="resizable2">
        <iframe class="mainContent" src="events.html"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is my css:

```css
.ui-resizable-helper {
    border: 1px dotted gray;
}

.resizable1 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 80%;
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.resizable2 {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    height: 80%;
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.menu {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 80%;
}

.mainContent {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    height: 80%;
}
```

This is my jQuery script:

```
$(function() {
        $(".resizable1").resizable({
            animate : true,
            animateEasing : 'swing',
            imateDuration : 500
        });
        $(".resizable2").resizable({
            animate : true,
            animateEasing : 'swing',
            imateDuration : 500
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: A jsFiddle would be perfect for this

Comment: iFrames are only used for cross domain use, such as youtube videos or facebook walls on your website. Do not use iFrames for local files, there are much better ways to display site content.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above, I would suggest resizing them manually, but if you want to keep the animation, maybe do something like this: (restrict height with the containment attribute and try to calculate what the new width needs to be to manually resize the second one after the first one is resized)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cuzke/)

Added a container in HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="resizable1">
        <iframe class="menu" src="www.google.com">
            bla
        </iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="resizable2">
        <iframe class="mainContent" src="www.yahoo.com"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Set height in CSS:

```
.ui-resizable-helper {
    border: 1px dotted gray;
}
#container{
    height: 500px;
    width: 600px;
}
.resizable1 {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.resizable2 {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.menu {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 80%;
}

.mainContent {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    height: 80%;
}
```

Manually resized in jquery (doesn't fully work sorry, hope this is helpful)

```
$(function() {
        $(".resizable1").resizable({
            animate : true,
            animateEasing : 'swing',
            imateDuration : 500,
            containment: '#container'
        });
        $(".resizable2").resizable({
            animate : true,
            animateEasing : 'swing',
            imateDuration : 500,
            containment: '#container'
        });
    $(".resizable1").resize(
        function(e){
            var fullWidth = $("#container").innerWidth();
            var r1Width = $(".resizable1").outerWidth();
            $(".resizable2").width(fullWidth - r1Width-6);
            var r2Width = $(".resizable2").outerWidth();
            console.log(r1Width+" + "+r2Width+" = "+fullWidth);
        }
    );
});
```